# How does Nokogiri handle unclosed HTML tags like <br>?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

When parsing HTML document, how Nokogiri handle `<br>` tags? Suppose we have document that looks like this one:

```
<div>
   Hi <br>
   How are you? <br>
</div>
```

Do Nokogiri know that `<br>` tags are something special not just regular XML tags and ignore them when parsing node feed? I think Nokogiri is that smart, but I want to make sure before I accept this project involving scraping site written as HTML4. You know what I mean (`How are you?` is not a content of the first `<br>` as it would be in XML).

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect (or are trying to avoid)?  For example, do you want to make sure that the text of the "div" element is "Hi How are you?" instead of just "Hi" and "How are you?" is the text of the first "`<br>`" element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must parse this fragment using the HTML parser, as obviously this is not valid XML.  When using the HTML one, Nokogiri then behaves as you'd expect it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<-EOS
<div>
   Hi <br>
   How are you? <br>
</div>
EOS
)

doc.xpath("//br").each{ |e| puts e }
```

prints

```
<br>
<br>
```

Mechanize is based on Nokogiri for doing web scraping, so it is quite appropriate for the task.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you and I "expect" it to do is the same as what the OP expects. The statement in the question _"... `<br>` tags are something special [...] ignore them when parsing the node feed"_ is not what Nokogiri does, but appears to be what Kreeki is hoping for.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing that out! Having the parser return them means they can be handled rather than having to do a string replacement, which is what I was trying to imply. If the OP wants to ignore them, then something like `doc.xpath("//div").each { |e| puts e.text }`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how Nokogiri behaves when parsing (malformed) **XML**:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML("<div>Hello<br>World</div>")
puts doc.root
#=> <div>Hello<br>World</br></div>
```

Here's how Nokogiri behaves when parsing **HTML**:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<div>Hello<br>World</div>")
puts doc.root
#=> <html><body><div>Hello<br>World</div></body></html>

p doc.at('div').text
#=> "HelloWorld"
```

I'm assuming that by "something special" you mean that you want Nokogiri to treat it like a newline in the source text. A `<br>` is *not* something special, and so appropriately Nokogiri does *not* treat it differently than any other element.

If you want it to be treated as a newline, you can do this:

```
doc.css('br').each{ |br| br.replace("\n") }
p doc.at('div').text
#=> "Hello\nWorld"
```

Similarly, if you wanted a space instead:

```
doc.css('br').each{ |br| br.replace(" ") }
p doc.at('div').text
#=> "Hello World"
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can remember from doing some HTML parsing last year it'll view them as separate.

EDIT: My bad, I've just got someone to send me the code and retested it, we ended up dealing with somethings including `<br>` separately.